# Magento 2.3.5p1 custom theme Products attributes not reflecting on Frontend?

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute, custom-theme

I have created product attribute "Resources" & enabled "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront". Still I am not able to get the output on the frontend. There is already two tabs with the name of "Features" & "Specification" which are reflecting on frontend. New attributes are not reflecting.
Removed cache, flushed cache , reindexed already. Still nothing in showing.

Here is my code of catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
    <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title"/>
            <move element="product.content.shortdescription" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
            <move element="product.content.specifications" destination="product.info.main" after="product.content.shortdescription"/>
            <move element="product.content.suitabletext" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
            <move element="product-page-contact-btn" destination="product.info.main" before="product.content.shortdescription"/>
            <container name="image.media.container" as="someContainer" label="ImageMedia Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-container-media" >
            </container>
             <container name="info.main.container" as="infoContainer" label="Info Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-container-info" >
            </container>
             <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media custom-data-img" after="product.info.main">
            </container>
           <move element="info.main.container" destination="content" before="-"/>
            <move element="image.media.container" destination="info.main.container" before="-"/>
            <move element="product.info.media" destination="image.media.container" before="-"/>

           <move element="product.info.main" destination="info.main.container" after="-"/>

      <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />
      <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true"/>
      <!-- <remove name="product.info.addtocart"/> -->

      <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true"/>
      <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
      <referenceBlock name="product.review.form" remove="true" />
      <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
      <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
      <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
      <referenceBlock name="view.addto.wishlist" remove="true" />
      <referenceBlock name="product.price.final" remove="true"/>
      <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true" />
      <referenceBlock name="product.info.social" remove="true"/>
      <referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/>
<move element="contact-us-product-page" destination="content" after="product.info.main"/>
<move element="product-page-category-text" destination="product.info.main" before="page.main.title"/>
<move element="product-page-back-category-text" destination="product.info.media" after="-"/>


<move element="product.info.media" destination="image.media.container" after="-"/>
 <referenceContainer name="content"> 
            <block as="shortdescription" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" group="detailed_info" name="product.content.shortdescription" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getfeatures</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">features</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">features</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Features</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Features</argument>
                     <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block as="shortdescription" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" group="detailed_info" name="product.content.specifications" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSpecifications</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">specifications</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">specifications</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Specifications</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Specifications</argument>
                   <!--  <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop=&quot;description&quot;</argument> -->
                     <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="specifications"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            
             <block as="suitabletext" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" group="detailed_info" name="product.content.suitabletext" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSuitableText</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">suitable_text</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">suitable_text</argument>
                   <!--  <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Suitable Text</argument> -->
                    <!-- <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Specifications</argument> -->
                   <!--  <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop=&quot;description&quot;</argument> -->
                     <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="suitable_text"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="contact-us-product-page" after="-">
                 <arguments>
                  <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">contact-us-product-page</argument>
                  </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product-page-category-text">
                 <arguments>
                  <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">product-page-category-text</argument>
                  </arguments>
                </block>
<!-- <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product-page-back-category-text">
<arguments>
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">product-page-back-category-text</argument>
</arguments>
</block> -->
                  <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product-page-contact-btn">
                 <arguments>
                  <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">product-page-contact-btn</argument>
                  </arguments>
                </block>
              </referenceContainer>



    </body>
</page>
```